# Biometria no Android

Tags: java, android, autenticação, app

Olá a todos do StackOverflow. Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento Android, e acabei de desenvolver um aplicativo, agora quero melhorar ele, colocando como forma de entrada no mesmo o sistema de biometria, de forma que tem uma tela inicial com um botão entrar, quando clicar nesse botão quero que haja uma autenticação do sistema com a(as) biometria(as) cadastrada(as) e se conferir, aí o usuário é levado para outra activity. Já pesquisei sobre, olhei o no site Android Developers, pesquisei aqui no StackOverflow tanto português quanto inglês, mas não encontrei nada que me ajudasse, tem até essa pergunta parecida já aberta, porém sem resposta,

```
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/354480/solicitar-permissão-para-autenticação-biometrica
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar fico muito agradecido. Estou desenvolvendo um app para android 8.0 ou superior. Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.

Eu sei que no android atual preciso pedir permissão ao usuário quando ele inicia o app ou antes de usar o serviço, é outra coisa que não entendi como preciso fazer.

Agradeço pela atenção e qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Answer (score 1):

Prezado Gabriel, segue a classe MainActivity, XML e as dependências que deve ser informada no build.gradle.
Fazendo dessa forma não tem erro e você poderá abrir seu aplicativo com a digital, pois eu uso esse código em todos meus aplicativos como LOGIN.

```java
package ricciandroid.com.br.biometria;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

        import com.an.biometric.BiometricCallback;
        import com.an.biometric.BiometricManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BiometricCallback {

    private Button button;
    BiometricManager mBiometricManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.btn_authenticate);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                /*
                 *
                 * */
                mBiometricManager = new BiometricManager.BiometricBuilder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.biometric_title))
                        .setSubtitle(getString(R.string.biometric_subtitle))
                        .setDescription(getString(R.string.biometric_description))
                        .setNegativeButtonText(getString(R.string.biometric_negative_button_text))
                        .build();

                //start authentication
                mBiometricManager.authenticate(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onSdkVersionNotSupported() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.biometric_error_sdk_not_supported), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBiometricAuthenticationNotSupported() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.biometric_error_hardware_not_supported), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBiometricAuthenticationNotAvailable() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.biometric_error_fingerprint_not_available), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBiometricAuthenticationPermissionNotGranted() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.biometric_error_permission_not_granted), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBiometricAuthenticationInternalError(String error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
//        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.biometric_failure), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationCancelled() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.biometric_cancelled), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //mBiometricManager..cancelAuthentication();
    }



    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccessful() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.biometric_success), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpCode, CharSequence helpString) {
//        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), helpString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, CharSequence errString) {
//        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_authenticate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/connect"
        android:text="@string/btn_authenticate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

NO BUILD.GRADLE INSIRA ESSAS DEPENDÊNCIAS

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation(group: 'com.an.biometric', name: 'biometric-auth', version: '0.1.0', ext: 'aar', classifier: '')
}
```